# What penalties do reaction shots receive?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

I was looking through the Sniper skill tree and saw this skill:

> Opportunist: Eliminates the Aim penalty on reaction shots, and allows
>   reaction shots to cause critical hits.

Until reading that, I didn't even realize that reaction shots had an aim penalty and couldn't cause crits. What kind of aim penalty do they normally receive? Are there any other sorts of penalties?

Comment: The aim penalty is mentioned in the tooltip for "overwatch" - although it doesn't give specifics.  A [forum post](http://forums.2kgames.com/showthread.php?151661-What-s-the-penalty-for-firing-on-Overwatch) says 10% to-hit penalty, but I don't know how much I trust that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually those are the only two penalties to reaction shots I have encountered. At the exact second your character starts to fire, it is as if the enemy was standing there at that moment and told them to shoot and then subtract the aim penalty (-20 I think). In addition you can use this to your advantage and place a smoke where your character is dashing through. You will gain the defense boost if you are shot at while in the smoke.

Finally, I do know that there are bonuses you and enemies gain when moving or more specifically when dashing. When an enemy is dashing they are a moving target and have a higher defense and thus harder to hit. The combined reduction of accuracy from overwatch and dashing bonus from the enemy makes it very hard to hit reaction shots.

That specific perk basically removes all penalties to using overwatch on a sniper. It's pretty good when combined with squad sight.

This is all only in my experience however and I can't check what the enemy chances to hit are. I'd like to do some testing in multiplayer if possible.

Comment: I really love the combination of squad sight + reaction shot from the sniper, and if your sniper is at a high elevation, the shot is almost guaranteed to hit for tons of damage.